# Finding out the accuracy of the current probe's measurement

Tags: current, oscilloscope, probe, accuracy

As part of power supply testing we are measuring the current profiles of various regulators.

Startup profiles includes current bursts with different current amplitudes and widths.

i want to understand the accuracy of the current probe*(MINIMUM CURRENT WHICH CAN BE MEASURED ACCURATELY UPTO 1% to 3%)* in measuring currents.

For example in my case,
I have TCP0030A current probe from Tek-

it has 2 ranges 5A and 30A.

**1. whether in both ranges the accuracy differs or same**

It has different specifications like

DC gain accuracy <3%(1% typical) - **i am not sure what is this exactly?**

Displayed RMS noise <75uArms

1mA sensitivity- **Is this directly relates to Minimum current can be measured with this probe**

If i want to find the accuracy of the measurement, how i can derive error from all above error sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensitivity (1 mA) is the smallest current that can be consistently sensed by the instrument, i.e. it is guaranteed that you will get some reading with anything above 1 mA.

The gain accuracy tells you your measurement accuracy as a percentage of the measurement itself, so if you are sensing 1 A you can expect +-3%, typically +-1%.

The figures above are true for a properly calibrated, degaussed, warmed up and auto zeroed probe.

Comment: :Thanks. If i measure 1.5A using probe in scope, it means 1.5A+/-45mA (with 3%). Will it be same for whole range (30A or 5A)?I believe the probe mentioned is a hybrid probe which uses transformer for Higher currents and Hall effect sensor for Low currents - even though both are different sensors is the accuracy remains same?

Comment: That is a question that is answered on the datasheet... If they only give 3% figure both for 5 A and 30 A then yes, the error is the same.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any specific reason behind mentioning the accuracy as "DC Gain Accuracy"

Comment: Yes, it is gain accuracy only. Total accuracy depends on gain, offset, linearity, noise... Probably there is a tempco as well.